# Open a component in new tab

Tags: angular

I want to open my component "template1" in a new tab so I create a path :

```
const routes: Routes = [

{path : 'template1' , component: Template1Component} ];
```

and in the html :

```
<a  mat-raised-button color="primary" target="_blank" [routerLink]= "['/template1']">go</a>
```

Expected to open the component template1 in an empty page but it is created in the same page of the current component like that :

This is what I found when I click on "go":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your HTML or routing module. Try to restart and check again your server.

Comment: I think problem with that mat button with <a> tag. Why didn't you try to use click event with router navigate?

Comment: I tried but it is always the same problem ! I think it is because angular is a single page application the component cannot be opened in a new tab

Comment: No. That's not the problem. target  _blank working with angular also :(